# Change the signal state only if the signal has been constant for a certain time frame

Tags: matlab, simulink, simulink-library

My Simulink model has a subsystem that outputs a signal that I want to use to activate another subsystem. I only want to activate the other subsystem if the output signal of the first subsystem has had the value 1 for at least 30 seconds. If the signal changes to 0, I want to deactivate the subsystem again. I don't have much experience with Simulink, so I'm unsure if there is a built-in way to do this or if i need to implement this behavior myself in a function block with the help of timestamps.